# Active Model Serializers error on creating url attributes with v0.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I'm trying to do something super simple in AMS where I generate the url attribute for an object like below:

```
class DeckSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :description, :url

  has_one :user
  has_many :cards

  def url
    deck_url(object)
  end
end
```

However, I get the following error:

**ArgumentError: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true**

I'm currently using Rails 4.2.0 and AMS 0.9.3

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a known bug mentioned here:

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/573

I switched the AMS version to 0.8.3 and everything worked. While not a complete solution, it works for the time being. Interested in hearing thoughts from others

Answer (score 1):

This is a DIY way to solve this problem. Create a field on the model to store the url. then after the object has been saved, you update it with a manually generated url like this.
here is how i solved it.

```
if @questionsolution.save
generatedurl = 'http://localhost:3000/questionsolutions/' + @questionsolution.id.to_s
        @questionsolution.update(solutionurl: generatedurl)
end
```

then you can get the url from the resource direclty without depending on active model serializers to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'` in `config/environments/development.rb`